# How to find python installation directory on Ubuntu

Tags: 12.04, software-installation, python, paths

I have just migrated from Windows environment. I have installed Python 3.2 in a separate directory. How can I get the python installation path in Ubuntu shell?

Is there any way I can let the shell know/choose at runtime which python version is to be used for further code execution?

Are there any environment variables and search path kind of things in Ubuntu Linux as well?

Answer (score 108, accepted):

**First question:**

`which python` though its usually `/usr/bin/python` for the 2.7

**Second question:**

From a terminal & python2.7: `python2.7 yourfile.py`.
Simailarly for 3.2: `python3.2 yourfile.py` though 3.2 isn't installed by default. (You can `apt-get install python3.2`.)

What `python yourfile.py` will do depends on which alternative is used for your python interpreter. You can change that by issuing `update-alternatives python` as `root` (or by using `su`).

**Third question:**

Environment variables are shell dependent, though you can write them out with `echo $variable` and set them with `variable=value` (from `bash`). The search path is simply called `PATH` and you can get yours by typing `echo $PATH`.

I hope this was helpful.

Comment: Thanks @Wolfer ! Answer was indeed helpful and much appreciated. If somebody like me has changed default python 3 installation path then .. ? How can I check path and run using this version ?

Comment: Also, I am not getting any output for $echo $variable

Comment: `which python2.7` and `which python3.2` will return each interpreter's install path (or return nothing if it's not installed).

Answer (score 53):

If you want to find the location of a program you can just use `whereis <program>`.

In your case run:

```
whereis python2.7
whereis python3.2
```

For finding every file that apt-get has copied for installation use:

```
dpkg -S python2.7
dpkg -S python3.2
```

But maby it is recommend to save it in a textfile, because the output is to large.

```
dpkg -S python2.7 >log.txt
gedit log.txt
```

for running .py file with python 3.2

```
python3.2 <file.py>
```

Comment: Thanks @Thomas ! This command 'whereis python2.7' is displaying many paths, but I think there has to be single python installation directory !

Comment: dpkg -S python2.7 shows all the files of python2.7. "/usr/lib/python2.7" is the directory of python2.7.

Comment: I m a bit confused, /usr/bin/python is the default shebang we use while python package is located at /usr/lib/python2.7 ? Is that true ??

Comment: /usr/lib/python is the program. In linux evry file can be a program. If you come from window it is confused.

Answer (score 12):

Here is a simple way, run in terminal:

```
type -a python
```

or

```
type -a python3
```

Comment: This is a great answer. Old schooled bash to the rescue :D Thankyou for sharing

Comment: A little bit of detail about what the `type` command is and what it does, particularly with the `-a` argument, would be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

For `Python2.7`

```
whereis python2.7
```

For `Python3.2`

```
whereis python3.2
```

For `Python 3.8`

```
which python3
```

or

```
whereis python3
```

Comment: Doesn't really add anything to the other answers...

Comment: @Ravexina `Python 3.8` and made it little simple.

Answer (score 0):

In the Python interprete, run these two commands:

```py
>>> import sys
>>> sys.path
```

and one of those outputs will be the installation path