# Can't find Python2.7 when trying to install Django in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, python, python-2.7

I'm using [this tutorial](http://shivul.wordpress.com/2010/05/07/installing-django-with-postgresql-on-windows-and-ubuntu/) to install Django with Postgresql in my Ubuntu 14.04.

In the 4th step, it asked me to go to my python directory, so I ran `$ whereis python2.7` and I got multiple directories. One is the shortcut stored in `/usr/bin`, one is a library in `usr/lib/python2.7`, and there are many others.

And because of this very reason, I'm not sure where I am supposed to navigate to find my Python directory and continue the installation.

Comment: check this http://askubuntu.com/questions/262063/how-to-find-python-installation-directory-on-ubuntu

Comment: @devav2 Already seen.

Answer (score 2):

That tutorial doesn't make sense or is really old.

First you should be aware that this tutorial is intended to install the development Django version, not a stable one. While this can make sense to develop Django programs or to learn it, it's probably a very, very bad idea to do for production.

Second, it's not going to work, Django now uses git to manage its source code, not subversion. If you really want to install the development version, use the [official guide](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/install/#installing-development-version). You should read it, but if you have git and pip installed (you should) just issue this two commands.

```
git clone git://github.com/django/django.git django-trunk sudo pip
install -e django-trunk/
```

Comment: Okay, I'll try that, and yes, this is for learning only, it shouldn't be a problem, should it? Also, if I'm uploading the website in a web host online and not in my computer, will it still matter if I use the same stuff?

Comment: The development version will have more bugs than a stable one. And it's ever changing, so it will be quite hard to have exactly the same version in the online server and your development machine, this can lead to hard to find problems. But django dev versions are usually quite safe, it's quite unlikely that you run into the above problem (but possible).